# bazel build failed after updated command line tool in Mac

Tags: xcode, tensorflow, gcc, build-process, bazel

Recently I updated command line tool in my Mac as required, but after that, my bazel build is not working, can you help advise how to fix it? thanks in advance

```
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_me/57d181a2c7179aa428276012ffbf756a/external/com_google_protobuf/BUILD:135:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/mathlimits.cc':
  '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h'
  '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/__stddef_max_align_t.h'
  '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/float.h'
  '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stdint.h'
  '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stdarg.h'
  '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/limits.h'
Target //java/com/myproject/target:build-deployment failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 5.268s, Critical Path: 2.42s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48155976/bazel-undeclared-inclusions-errors-after-updating-gcc

Comment: Hi @Laurent thanks for your help,  it is very useful,  do bazel clean --expunge can fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue to: [bazel "undeclared inclusion(s)" errors after updating gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48155976/bazel-undeclared-inclusions-errors-after-updating-gcc)
(Resolved with `bazel clean --expunge`)