# bazel missing dependency declarations for stddef.h and others Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bazel

I am trying to build an existing project using bazel, but get complains of the form

```
ERROR: .../BUILD:115:1: Couldn't build file xxx.o: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '@yyy:
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by zzz.c':
'/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stddef.h'
'/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stdarg.h'
'/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stdint.h'
'/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stdalign.h'
```

I am just setting up this code base, and I believe that other people can build.
It seems that I should not have to declare system include paths, especially in other people's code. Other people don't seem to have this problem. Did I inadvertently skip a setup step?

```
bazel version: 0.19.2
gcc version: 7.3.0
clang version: 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
```

Is there perhaps a .bazelrc file in which I can specify that system headers do not need to be explicitly declared?

Comment: Workaround: Downgrading gcc from 7.3 to 5.5 overcame those problems. This is quite surprising, since bazel is so multi-platform, I didn't expect that it would be so compiler dependent.

Answer (score 7):

Same problem after upgrade to 18.04.

Fixed by:

1. Completely clearing bazel cache as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48524741,

And

2. Uninstalling bazel and re-installing again from scratch.

Comment: Clearing the cache was sufficient for me.

Comment: `bazel clean --expunge`, as in the linked answer.